# Python: displaying random dots in coordinate system

Tags: python, matplotlib

Im trying to make a program that displays random dots on a coordinate system. Im new to Python so i do not completely understand the syntax so I could really use some help! Atm my program is only displaying a dot at (0,0).

Code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random

x = 0
y = 0

for a in range(0,9):
   i = random.randint(0,9)
   j = random.randint(0,9)

   x = x + i
   y = y + i

   plt.scatter(x,y)
   plt.show()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the correct way to do this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

N = 9

x = np.random.rand(N)
y = np.random.rand(N)

plt.scatter(x,y)
plt.show()
```

[Random sampling](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.random.html#numpy.random.random).